# What does it mean to to set path to jdk8 when running gradle 6,7,8?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am receiving the following error

```
  Information:Gradle tasks [:omniNotes:assembleDebug]
    Warning:Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
             In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
    Warning:Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
             In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
    :omniNotes:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:checkDebugManifest
    :omniNotes:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareBeBillingtonCalendarRecurrencepickerLibrary111Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareChAcraAcra470RC1Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2321Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72321Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2321Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72321Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2321Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComArtemzinRxjavaProguardRules10142Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComGetbaseFloatingactionbutton1101Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComGithubAfollestadMaterialDialogsCommons0856Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComGithubAfollestadMaterialDialogsCore0856Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComGithubFedericoiosueChecklistview313Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComGithubFedericoiosuePixlui25Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComGithubFedericoiosueSimpleGallery120Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComGithubFlavienlaurentDatetimepickerLibrary002Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComGithubGabrielemariottiChangeloglibChangelog200Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComGithubPaolorotoloAppintro130Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase810Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement810Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation810Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps810Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComLarswerkmanHoloColorPicker14Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComNhaarmanListviewanimationsLibCore310Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComNhaarmanListviewanimationsLibManipulation310Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComPnikosisMaterialishProgress15Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComPushbulletAndroidExtensions104Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComSquareupLeakcanaryLeakcanaryAndroid13Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareComTbruyelleRxpermissionsRxpermissions042Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareDeKeyboardsurferAndroidWidgetCrouton184Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareIoNlopezSmartlocationLibrary320Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareIoReactivexRxandroid101Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareMeZhanghaiAndroidMaterialprogressbarLibrary114Library UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:prepareDebugDependencies
    :omniNotes:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
    :omniNotes:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
    Error:Execution failed for task ':omniNotes:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

> When running gradle with java 5, 6 or 7, you must set the path to jdk8, either with property retrolambda.jdk or environment variable JAVA8_HOME

```
    Information:BUILD FAILED
    Information:Total time: 13.861 secs
    Information:1 error
    Information:2 warnings
    Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: which version of `java` currently you working on ? @`ambharath

Comment: @VikrantKashyap jdk1.7.0_51

Comment: this is your first build or have you ever build this successfully ? @1ambharath

Comment: @VikrantKashyap This is an imported project .

Comment: please set the `variablename` as `JAVA8_HOME`. Please don't paly with `path` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that gradle is looking for Java 8. See if you can set it to use Java 7 as you already have that. If you want to set JAVA8_HOME, find where you have Java 8 installed on your system. Usually its C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8. Now do the following

1. Right-click the My Computer icon on your desktop and select Properties.
2. Click the Advanced tab.
3. Click the Environment Variables button.
4. Under System Variables, click New.
5. Enter the variable name as JAVA8_HOME.
6. Enter the variable value (one of the paths mentioned above) as the
   installation path for the Java Development Kit.
7. Click OK.
8. Click Apply Changes.

Comment: In short , I need to install jdk8 , too ? or will simply changing the path name to JAVA8_HOME will work ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with retrolambda, but looking at the documentation, it seems you have to install jdk8. [gradle-retrolambda/README.md](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: You could give it a try by setting JAVA8_HOME to your jdk7. From the above linked page `jdk Set the path to the java 8 jdk. The default is found using the environment variable JAVA8_HOME. If you a running gradle with java 5, 6 or 7, you must have either JAVA8_HOME or this property set.`

Comment: Had to install new jdk8 , and then update it to JAVA8_HOME path variable

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install a `JAVA_1.8` First.

and add a new Environment System variable named `JAVA8_HOME` which contains the `jdk_1.8` path.

```
"JAVA8_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8"
```

this might solve your problem. if you don't know how to set System Variables then you can do as like this

1. Select Start, select Control Panel. double click System, and select the Advanced tab.
2. Click Environment Variables. ...
3. In the  New System Variable window, specify the value of the `JAVA8_HOME` environment variable. ...

Comment: Doing the same , download in progress

Comment: have you completed your download and setup procedures ?? @1ambharath